# Creating a folder without space is failing

Tags: cmd, qml, mkdir

I have a pure QML application where I'm trying to create a folder with a `QProcess` on Windows.

If the path I'd like to create contains a space it is working.

If the path I'd like to create DOES NOT contain a space it is NOT working.

QML function:

```
function mkdir(qproc, path) {
    var cmd;
    var res = false;
    // Platform-based command
    switch (Qt.platform.os) {
    case "windows":
        cmd = "cmd /s /c mkdir \"" + path + "\"";
        break;
    default:
        cmd = "/bin/sh -c \"mkdir -p '"+path+"'\"";
    }

    qproc.start(cmd);
    res = qproc.waitForFinished(5000);
    }
```

Which ends up as DOS commands:

Path with space: `cmd /s /c mkdir "D:/Misc/temp/A Folder/"` ==> `A Folder` is created

Path without space: `cmd /s /c mkdir "D:/Misc/temp/AFolder/"` ==> `AFolder` is NOT created

Two remarks:

- the `\s` flag seems having no effect, neither positive nor negative (I could remove it)
- launched individually in a cmd-prompt, the 2 calls are working. The issue seems to be in the QML<->cmd interaction.

Comment: The reason why it wouldn't work is the directory slashes are incorrect for Windows. They need to be backslashes. However, what is this `qproc` object? I would recommend creating directories using C++ and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdir.html#mkdir. Also, that `QDir` object would not have any issue with either forward slashes or backslashes. Is there a reason why you are not using C++?

Comment: I'm working in a special environment ([MuseScore plugin API](https://musescore.github.io/MuseScore_PluginAPI_Docs/plugins/html/)). In that context I don't have access to a C++ backend. The API exposes the C++ `QProcess` class as `QProcess` QML component. `qproc` is an instance of this `QProcess` component. This being said,  working with  `\ ` solved my problem. It is strange that folder names WITHOUT spaces require the `\ ` while folder names WITH spaces are working fine with `/`...

Comment: I'm not using `QDir` simply because it is not exposed to me (as mentioned I don't have access to the C++ backend. Only to what the MuseScore API is exposing). Besides `\s` has no effect. Neither negative nor positive. I've removed it.